# ¿Cómo cambiar a factor en tidyverse?

Tags: r, rstudio

Importo un fichero desde un csv sin problemas:

```
library("tidyverse")

archivo <- read_delim("Data/archivo.csv", delim = "\t")
archivo
```

Luego con tidyverse modifico algunas cosas:

```
archivo %>% 
    separate(FAMILIA, into = c("CODIGO", "FAMILIA"), sep = " - ") %>% 
    separate(FECHA, into = c("DIA", "MES", "AÑO"), convert = TRUE)
```

Este fichero tiene muchos campos, y me gustaría transformar unos cuantos, pero me estoy viendo con algunos problemas. Por ejemplo, tengo un campo que tiene valores del tipo:

- A - Valor A
- B - Valor B
- C - Valor C

Y con `separate()` lo que hago es generar dos campos, uno llamado CODIGO y otro FAMILIA, y que son:

- CODIGO | VALOR
- A      | Valor A
- B      | Valor B
- C      | Valor C

Pero esos valores son tipo carácter, y me gustaría que fuesen un factor por ejemplo, pero no veo la forma de convertirlo directamente usando `separate(`), porque he usado `convert = TRUE`, pero por lo que he visto en la ayuda sólo cambia a tipos numéricos o lógicos.

Y luego tengo otra duda, porque el fichero csv tiene muchos campos, ¿puedo de alguna forma generar un objeto archivo pero sólo de las columnas que me interesan de alguna manera también usando `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes hacerlo mediante `separate()`, la rutinas del universo `tidyverse` evitan las conversiones `character - factor`, si revisas la documentación del parámetro `convert`:

> If TRUE, will run type.convert() with as.is = TRUE on new columns.
> This is useful if the component columns are integer, numeric or
> logical.

Lo que dice, es que en caso de `TRUE` se ejecutará `type.convert()` con el parámetro `as.is = TRUE`, este parámetro establece justamente que los caracteres sean tratados como tal y no convertidos a un `factor`. Lamentablemente no te queda otra que hacer un `mutate()` para cambiar el tipo de columna:

```
data.frame(FAMILIA="CODIGO - VALOR") %>% 
  separate(FAMILIA, into = c("CODIGO", "FAMILIA"), sep = " - ") %>% 
  mutate(CODIGO = as.factor(CODIGO),
         FAMILIA = as.factor(FAMILIA)) %>% 
  str()

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ CODIGO : Factor w/ 1 level "CODIGO": 1
 $ FAMILIA: Factor w/ 1 level "VALOR": 1
```

NOTA: el parámetro `convert` es útil, cuando tienen números como cadenas y quieres que sean `numeric` entre otros casos.

Con respecto  a ignorar columnas con `read_delim()` es posible hacerlo, definiendo previamente el parámetro `col_types`. Por ejemplo:

```
read_delim("https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/raw/master/inst/extdata/mtcars.csv",
           delim=',',
           col_types = cols(
             mpg = col_double(),
             cyl = col_double(),
             disp = col_skip() ,
             hp = col_double(),
             drat = col_skip() ,
             wt = col_double(),
             qsec = col_double(),
             vs = col_skip() ,
             am = col_skip() ,
             gear = col_skip() ,
             carb = col_skip() 
           ))
```

Mediante la función `cols()` definimos el tipo de dato de cada columna, puedes entonces ignorar las que desees asignando la función `col_skip()`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando queremos cambiar el tipo de variable character u otras a factor para poder construir modelos de ml, podemos usar esta sintaxis. A mí me funciona:
Cuando construimos las variables como factores, estamos estableciendo grupos dentro de la variable FAMILIA, en este caso.
Puedes probar con la siguientes sintáxis:

`data.frame <- FAMILIA %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor), FAMILIA = as.factor(FAMILIA)) %>%`

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, por favor pulsa en editar y agrega cómo tu código soluciona el problema de OP. ;)